# SP Online - Code blocks are not allowed in this file

Tags: javascript, error, asp.net, aspx

I have built a selection of ASP.net controls on my default.aspx page. I am using the following line of javascript to try and get the value of an ASP control.

```
var imgUrl = document.getElementById("<%= backUrl.ClientID %>").value;
```

However this throws up the following error when I try to run my app on SP.

> Sorry, there was a problem with bannerSlide.
>   For support, please contact the developer. An error occurred during the processing of
>   /sites/dev/bannerSlide/Pages/test.aspx. Code blocks are not allowed in
>   this file.

Most online solutions seem to point towards modifying a web file but I don't think this is possible with SharePoint Online (Office 365).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Default.aspx is a Site Page and inline C# or VB code is not allowed in Site Pages. So you need to replace the code block (i.e. <%= backUrl.ClientID %>) with the literal id of the element.

Comment: You can use inline code even in site pages as long as the page is not customized, e.g. it has been deployed through a farm solution package. As soon as you edit it in Designer it will break. Still, this is no help to Ben for SP Online.